# Next struct item,incomplete type

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, field

```
struct node{  
    struct node next;  
    int id;  
}
```

gives "field next has incomplete type error ".

what is wrong with this struct ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When creating a self-referential data type, you need to use pointers to get around problems of circularity:

```
struct node;

struct node {  
    struct node * next;  
    int id;  
}
```

...should work, but take care to allocate memory correctly when using it.

Why a pointer? Consider this: the point of a `struct` definition is so that the compiler can figure out how much memory to allocate and what parts to access when you say `node.id`. If your `node` struct contains another `node` struct, how much memory should the compiler allocate for a given `node`?

By using a pointer you get around this, because the compiler knows how much space to allocate for a pointer.

Answer (score 5):

If a struct *could* contain another instance of its own type, its size would be infinite.

This is why it can only contain a *pointer* to its it own type.

Furthermore, at that point in code, the size of the struct is unknown, so the compiler couldn't know how much space to reserve for it.

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to do a forward-declaration of node, since the compiler doesn't know `node` yet while it's processing its definition.
2. You probably meant to store a pointer, not a node object itself.

Try this:

```
struct node;

struct node{  
    struct node *next;  
    int id;  
};
```

Comment: The forward declaration is not needed as the struct's declaration acts as its own forward declaration.  The issue is entirely that he tried to put a struct inside itself and should have used a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Some uses of incomplete types are ill-formed, such as when you try to declare an object of an incomplete type. However, you can declare a pointer to an incomplete type (for example). In this case that is just what is needed here:

```
struct node{  
    struct node *next;  
    int id;  
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, when the compiler reaches this line:

```
struct node{  
    struct node next;  /* << this line */
```

the compiler actually doesn't know what is `struct node`, because you're defining `struct node`.

In general, you cannot use a type which is not defined or incomplete.

Comment: Actually, the compiler *knows* that already. The real problem is that the `struct` will be of infinite size due to self-referentiality. The solution is to use a pointer (`struct node *next`). ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In order to work, you should write:

```
typedef struct _node{
  struct _node* next;
  int           id;
}node;
```

Comment: Identifiers that begin with an underscore are reserved for the implementation

Comment: awoodland: only underscore + capital letter or double underscores.