# incomplete type error with structures

Tags: c

Sorry to bother you, I'm new at c and I need help with something: I tried to create a structure that has inside of it an element of the same structure type (like a node tree in a tree, which can have children nodes). This is the code I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct vectorObject vectorObject;

struct vectorObject{
  int value; //Value of node
  int hasChildren; //1 if it has and 0 if not
  int level; //0 for leaf, 1 for leaf parent, 2 for parent of parent, etc...

  vectorObject leftSon;
  vectorObject rightSon;
};

vectorObject *listObjetos;
vectorObject *priorityQueue;


int main(void) {...}
```

The problem is that I keep getting this error

```
field 「leftSon」 has incomplete type
```

And I don't know what to do. In java you can create a class and this class can have itself as an object, because you are using objects, but here I don't know what happens. Could you please help me? Thank you so much and sorry to bother you.

Comment: The common idiom in C is to use pointers to the left and right children, rather than the actual structures themselves.

Comment: @OP: think about the structure of the structure (pun intended). Does it make sense to include a struct into itself? No (infinite recursion, that is). Use pointers.

Comment: Also: a structure can not contain itself, and certainly not two instances of itself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Struct X in Struct X?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16997922/struct-x-in-struct-x)

Comment: in java there are no explicit pointers...you can have a type that is has inside the same type..... the type variables in java are nothing but pointers....not objects.... what you create here using malloc is like object creation as you create there using `new` keyword

Comment: @pinkpanther misinterpreted your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C (unlike Java), the default is NOT object references. So, declaring an object like you have done, the compiler wants to know it's full size and composition - which is not available at the time of the declaration (because your definition is recursive).

The way around this is to explicitly use object references. In C, this is done by using pointers instead. This way, the compiler knows the size of the object being declared, because it knows the size of a pointer (which is fixed). It happily moves on to complete the definition, at which point the size and composition of the entire object is known.

```
struct vectorObject{
  int value; //Value of node
  int hasChildren; //1 if it has and 0 if not
  int level; //0 for leaf, 1 for leaf parent, 2 for parent of parent, etc...

  vectorObject* leftSon;
  vectorObject* rightSon;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I really appreciate it! (Today I learned something new :D )

Comment: +1) making this  clear to a person from c -> java is easy....but for java -> c it's really difficult....but you made him understood...